Is a 36K condenser adequate when a 40K load is calculated?
We have been working with an HVAC company to install electric heat pumps (mini splits) to provide heating and cooling for our home, located near Boston, Massachusetts.  The HVAC company calculated a 40K load for two seperate parts of our home, requiring two exterior condenser units.  The company told us that 48K units are not available for another few months so they suggested that we install two 36K units, instead.  When I questioned why we would install two 36K units when they calculated a load of 40K for each section of our home, it seems that I am getting pressured to purchase the 36K units now rather than wait for the 48K units to become available.
Is a 36K condenser the appropriate unit to install when a 40K load has been calculted?  Or should I wait until March to install two 48K units?

How often will you need max capacity? and for how long?

oversized is better than undersized

If you can ,wait for the 48K..   Senville has a 48K https://senville.com/48000-btu-five-zone-mini-split-air-conditioner-heat-pump-sena-48hf-f/?sku=SENA-48HF-F99999&gad_source=1&gclid=CjwKCAiAgoq7BhBxEiwAVcW0LIsEwD1IpARYPqHZNc2rzjl5zzq8M6_X6SDFFJcsn08rqUyLcgtzZRoCKYsQAvD_BwE  I have used them in a number of properties.  They work very well and customer service is great.

For AC, going too large can lead to cold humid interior conditions, and so for AC, typically I'd select something a bit undersized compared to oversized, to have the AC run longer to better remove humidity.  For heat, there isn't as much of a concern on the oversize, especially from a mini-spit.  Do you have other energy-saving improvements planned for the near future that might impact the load calculation and bring that down to the 36k range where the 36k would be sufficient.  I'm guessing the HVAC company is thinking that they'd rather get the sure money now, rather then the potential later.

The quality/amount of the homes insulation can have a large effect on the size of HVAC system/s needed.  Increasing low insulation values can reduce the HVAC size needed.  Maybe for similar cost to a larger sysytem.

@Milwrdfan,   The Senville units and some others have a setting on the head units to remove humidity.  It works exceptionally well.

Without seeing the calculations and diagrams of the house, it will be nearly impossible to answer this.  It can get very cold in the winter and very hot in the summer in Boston. Not a good idea to go with the undersized units unless the installers guarantee to install the 48K units at a later date free of charge if you're not happy with the preformance of the smaller units. Have they/you checked with other companies for the 48K?
